# Laravel-AdminLTE Modify register form

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

By default it has input of full name but my User model doesn't have and it uses first_name and last_name instead. How can I modify the form input having those fields instead of full name.

The file register.blade.php has only this code when applying this plugin

```
@extends('adminlte::register')
```

Link of the plugin: https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE

Answer (score 1):

I just didn't saw the part of the documentation. LOL

7. Customize views

If you need full control over the provided views, you can publish them:

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider" --tag=views
Now, you can edit the views in resources/views/vendor/adminlte.

Answer (score 1):

Simply execute in the comand line:

```sh
php artisan adminlte:install --only=main_views
```

This will install views in a sub-folder `layouts/vendor/adminlte/auth`.

Search and edit `register.blade.php` to modify the register form.